# SQLITE3 query syntax error

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I'm trying to update a table in my dataset. When I run the below query I get "**near "FROM": syntax error:**

I have tired and tired but no luck in figuring it out.

I'm using sqlite3 as a database and DB Browser to execute the query.

```
UPDATE movieDataset
SET budget=REPLACE(movie_info.info,',','')
FROM (
  SELECT
  movie_info.movie_id,
  movie_info.info
  FROM
  movie_info, movieDataset
  WHERE
  movieDataset.movie_id = movie_info.movie_id
  and movie_info.info_type_id=105
  )AS movie_info
  WHERE movieDataset.movie_id = movie_info.movie_id;
```

movieDataset column list: (movie_id integer, country, budget)

movie_info column list: (movie_id, info, movie_info_type_id)

Any suggestion???

Thank you

Comment: I didn't realise it was even a thing to have a `FROM` in an `UPDATE`. Isn't it just: `UPDATE table SET column = value WHERE x = y`

Comment: Sqlite doesn't support this syntax, only plain UPDATE , no FROM.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, update rows with `movie_id` which has `info_type_id=105` in corresponding `movie_info`row

```
UPDATE movieDataset
SET budget=REPLACE(movie_info.info,',','')
WHERE movieDataset.movie_id IN (
  SELECT movie_info.movie_id
  FROM movie_info
  WHERE movie_info.info_type_id=105
  )
```

Comment: This looks like a very reasonable answer to me.

Comment: Thank you serg for your help. I have tried your solution and i'm getting the same error.

Comment: Hi Serg, now i'm getting this error "no such column: movie_info.info. The info column is only in the movie_info table and not in movieDataset. I will outline all the columns in both tables in my question if that would help. Thanks again

Comment: Edit your question or may be ask another one regarding the problem to be solved with the query. Show sample data and the result needed.

Comment: Thank you for all your help Serg. I will write another question